# Feature interpretation in decision tree after OneHotEncoding

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to understand how are **features interpreted** by decision tree after performing **OneHotEncoding** on data to convert categorical data.

---

Let's say in training data we have 3 features(all categorical) as X1, X2, X3.

X1 has 3 distinct values (a,b,c),
X2 has 2 distinct values (e,f) and
X3 has 4 distinct values (m,n,o,p).

After encoding, with sparse = False, resultant matrix will be of shape (X.shape[0], 9).

---

Now while fitting the decision tree model, to calculate information gain, will the model consider this as training set of 9 features or of 3 features?

If 3, how will model know about the no. of columns associated with a feature.

If 9, won't the features lose their importance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every case, your model will work with what you give to it:

- If your dataset is of shape (X.shape[0], 9), it would mean that 9 features would have been generated from your 3 categorial. In which case, each feature become a boolean indicator (ie: if the column corresponding to X1 and value "a" have a value of 1 in a row, it would mean this row add value "a" in X1).
- In the other case, if your shape is (X.shape[0], 3), each column will have a set of  numerical value (ie: for X1 : "a" = 0.33 ; "b"=0.66; "c"=1.0), effectively encoding the characters in your categorial variable.

**To precisely answer your questions :**

> Now while fitting the decision tree model, to calculate information gain, will the model consider this as training set of 9 features or of 3 features?

The model will consider what you give it, if you give him data with shape (X.shape[0], 9) it will compute information gain on 9 features, if (X.shape[0], 3),  it will compute information gain on 3 features.

> If 3, how will model know about the no. of columns associated with a feature.

The point of **OneHotEncoding** if only to **convert an ensemble of unique string to an ensemble of unique floats/ints**. In essence IF gain don't care what your data look like, it's just the scikit-learn algorithm not accepting categorial variables. To IF gain, your OneHotEncoding result have the same "value" has your original data.

> If 9, won't the features lose their importance?

If your features are **boolean indicator** instead of encoded categorial column, do you loose any information ? In my point of view no, you just **represented** the information originaly present in your dataset in another format !

In theory, **with no limit of depth**, both approach should hold **similar results** as you just changed the representation, not the relation between the data and the classes you are trying to learn.

**The only difference** will be that, **if the spliting rules only consider one feature** (which is the case in sklearn), a rule based on the value of the an encoded feature (X1 : "a" = 0.33 ; "b"=0.66; "c"=1.0) **could seperate more cases in one split** than a boolean indicator.